# conversion operator and operator>>

Tags: c++

I have a program following:

```
class INT {
public:
  INT(int ii = 0) : i(ii) {}
  operator int() { return i; }
private:
  int i;
};

int main()
{
  INT i;
  cin >> i;
}
```

the statement `cin >> i` is compiled error, but I don't know the reason?

In my option, the compiler can find the function `cin.operator>>(int&)` for that statement, since `INT` can be converted to `int` through `INT::operator int()`.

Comment: Can you post the full compiler output? If that is your entire code, then it should be `std::cin`, not `cin`.

Comment: You Have declared INT as a class and i as an aboject of it inside main .

Comment: What actually do you want to do here ?

Comment: @Mat, any reason you changed the variables to uppercase?

Comment: @Xeo: no sorry that was an error, didn't realize it (using an editor script that does some auto-corrections, it's supposed to skip code blocks but seems to have failed here). Will be more careful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You `operator int()` returns a temporary, which can't bind to a reference-to-non-const that the `operator>>` expects (since it needs to change that variable).

Change that to `operator int&()` and add a `const` overload as `operator int const&() const`.

Answer (score 3):

You can do what you're trying to do by changing your `int` operator to make it return a reference:

```
operator int&() { return i; }
```

At the moment you are returning a copy of you integer, so even if the >> operator did work it wouldn't change the value of the original.

Answer (score 0):

My advice is to overload << and >> as friends so that it can access the private variables with the stream be passed in by references.

```
class INT {
public:
  INT(int i = 0) : _i(i) {}
  const int& getValue()const {return _i;}
  void setValue(int i){_i=i;}
  friend istream& operator>>(istream& in, INT& myINT);

private:
  int _i;
};

friend istream& operator>>(istream& in, INT& myINT){
   int x;
   in >> x;
   myINT.setValue(x);
   return in;
}
```